# bootstrap tabcollapse in iframe not working in IE11

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, iframe, tabs, internet-explorer-11

I have a need to run bootstrap-tabcollapse (swaps tabs to collapse in responsive mode) in an Iframe.

It works beautifully in Firefox, Safari and IE10 and earlier - just seems to be having a problem with IE11 (both Win 7 & 8.1).

In IE11 the tabs are not activating anything - works fine when viewed without the iframe.

**Demos here:**

In iframe: http://112.140.180.117/~adnovatest/test/

No iframe: http://112.140.180.117/~adnovatest/test/example.html

Is there some issue with IE11 and triggering tabs? Or have I overlooked something simple here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. In case anyone else looking for an answer needed to force IE to emulate IE10 so used:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10">
```

Must be placed in the header - only thing that can precede it is the title tag.

Comment: This awkward hack also appears to make IE behave correctly when you use bootstrap in a framed html page.  I have an example where a page works fine in IE11 but when exactly the same page is used as part of a frameset Bootstrap falls apart.  Adding this meta tag sorted it out.